# .htaccess redirect files ending with / or index.html to .shtml

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

After transferring my site to a new CMS which has a new file structure and file extension, I need to redirect all files ending with / or index.html to .shtml:

example.com/violent-crimes/assault-with-a-deadly-weapon/
to
example.com/violent-crimes/assault-with-a-deadly-weapon.shtml

example.com/violent-crimes/assault-with-a-deadly-weapon/index.html 
to
example.com/violent-crimes/assault-with-a-deadly-weapon.shtml

example.com/violent-crimes/index.html 
to
example.com/violent-crimes.shtml

example.com/violent-crimes/ 
to
example.com/violent-crimes.shtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root, above any rules that may already exist:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/|/index.html)$ /$1.shtml [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, also how do i redirect example.com/test.html to example.com/test.shtml